# Is any human using the grace Sunshine destined to die, or you only would die if you overuse it?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

If I understand correctly, Escanor died because the grace Sunshine was too much for him

> However, as Sunshine is a power made for a Goddess Clan's member, Escanor cannot resist the effects of using that power on his human body[2], damaging him to the point of coughing blood[3] and finally eating away his body.

[Sunshine](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Sunshine)

Then, how about Gawain? Is she destined to die too because she has that grace?